# I was a privilege but not anymore, what am I?

Tags: riddle

> In the past, I was a privilege
>
> But now I am like everyone else
>
> You can't describe me to someone who can't see
>
> I can be a warning
>
> I can also be symbolising the thing most people seek
>
> I am one of the three, yet there are many more.

What am I?

Comment: For future puzzles I advise you don't do so many riddles. They are looked down upon more often than not and are hard to write good ones without them being too broad or too easy

Comment: But you've still done well or your first day, I'll look forward to seeing more puzzles

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, I guess today I had some muse for such riddles. I will try thinking of different types of puzzles. I am dry for now. :)

Comment: Explore some of the other puzzles on this site from some of the more experienced users for ideas and you'll be an experienced user yourself in no time at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are

> the colour red.

In the past, I was a privilege

> Purple, a specific red, was reserved for high nobles.

But now I am like everyone else

> This is no longer the case.

You can't describe me to someone who can't see

> Colours cannot be described to a blind, as they only exist as visual perception.

I can be a warning

> Red is a warning colour.

I can also be symbolising the thing most people seek

> Love is associated to the colour red.

I am one of the three, yet there are many more.

> Red is one of the three primary colours, but there are of course many more than three colours.